# Script execution in loaded HTML fragments: PrototypeJS -> jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, prototypejs

I am currently working on a pretty involved content piece that is supposed to live within the confines of my CMS. Part of this content piece is supposed to import an html block and also fire a script within that block. This works great when using Prototype.js, but it has caused major conflicts that none of the jQuery.noConflict() solutions have resolved.

Is there a way to recreate this Prototype.js Ajax function with jquery or straight Javascript? I know how to get the html chunch, my issue is the firing of the script that is contained within the html block.

Here is the Prototype.js script I have been using till the conflict appeared:

```
function myAjaxCallRig1() {
    new Ajax.Updater('first-cont-rig', 'http://ektrondev.nov.com/OTC/Home/html_content/rig-cont1.html', {method: 'get', evalScripts: 'true'});
}
```

Thank you!

Comment: `jQuery.noConflict` is used to prevent clashes on pages where jQuery is loaded multiple times in possibly different versions. From how I understand, this is not the case in your question. But what exactly is the "conflict" you experience? It would be helpful if you would include the jQuery AJAX call you have tried to replace the PrototypeJS code with. Take a look at "Script execution" for [jQuery.load](http://api.jquery.com/load/#script-execution).

Comment: jQuery.load did exactly what I needed it to. Thank you for leading me in the right direction. I would like to mark your answer as the solution but it is not allowing me to.

Comment: Glad to hear it worked! On Stackoverflow, only answers can be accepted as the correct solution, but not comments. I've added one now.

Answer (score 0):

jQuery offers the [`.load()`](http://api.jquery.com/load/) AJAX helper for loading snippets of markup and including it into your page.

In its default invocation (without a filtering expression given as a parameter), it executes `<script>` tags present in the loaded markup:

> When calling .load() using a URL without a suffixed selector expression, the content is passed to .html() prior to scripts being removed. This executes the script blocks before they are discarded.